# Identification of Bird feather, probably from a predatory bird

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

[image]

Found in Berlin,Germany
Area of Charlottenburg
I want to know the species of this bird, someone please tell me.
Approximate size 19 cm

Comment: Have you seen this (German) page: http://www.greifvogelhilfe.de/artenbestimmung/gefieder-greifvoegel/ ? That might help to narrow down the number of candidates.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Common Kestrel (Falco tinnunculus) primary wing feather, so it is indeed from a predatory bird. The orange hue suggests that this came from a juvenile and/or female individual. Featherbase provides a good reference [here](https://www.featherbase.info/en/exhibit/1120).

For future feather identification questions, you may wish to post them to the [Found Feathers project](https://www.inaturalist.org/projects/found-feathers) on iNaturalist.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This looks like a good answer, but you are more likely to get a positive response if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. (Note that answers must stand on their own — i.e not require us to follow links.) ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 